# Newly created site collection could not be found

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, site-collection, url, web-application

I have a fresh SharePoint 2013 on 2008r2 installation. I create a new web application with default settings but instead of the default public url, I enter http://qwe:
[image]

I go on to create a site collection sc1. The site is created but when I try to open http://qwe/sites/sc1, I receive an error message **qwe's server DNS address could not be found**

I realize it's a silly question, especially given the error message, but after reading on [Update a web application URL and IIS bindings for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262366.aspx) and similar topics I still seem to be getting nowhere.

Could someone give me a hand and explain the step I am missing?

1. Site collections created under default url, e.g. http://WIN-2TED5E2GK7G:7031/sites/testsite work without issues.
2. The site and web application are created and visible under Powershell:
   [image]
3. Apart from the steps mentioned, I did NOT configure any bindings, alternate mappings or DNS settings for the web application.

Comment: You need to access your site using **http://qwe:7031/sites/sc1** as you didn't use any AAM in it so you should try it using webapplicationname with port number in URL.

Comment: are you able to access http://qwe/ (SharePoint - 8034) ?

Comment: Neither http://qwe/  nor http://qwe:8034/sites/sc1  (server DNS address could not be found)

Comment: @grisha Did you ever figure out the solution to this? I'm experiencing the same problem as you. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/244371/65053

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you miss the most important root level site collection.

Could you please create the root level site collection on **qwe** web app. this site should be on "/" path. When you go to Create new site collection, Select "/" in the managed path.

Comment: Valid point, but not a solution. The error message is still the same after I have created the root site.

Comment: Have you tried using port number like this http://qwe:8034/sites/sc1

Comment: Yes, same issue.

Comment: what is qwe? is it  DNS? i dont think it is server name, right? Server name looks like  WIN-2TED5E2GK7G. if you dont have dns then you have to create one or on the pc from where you accessing the site add host file entry for qwe

Comment: qwe is just a sample name I put when creating a web application. How would such an entry look like? ::8034 qwe  ?   localhost:8034  gives me access denied

Comment: You cant use any name in the URL, it should be either a dns entry or use the host file which resolve it to the server. localhost:8034 giving you access denied thats mean the account which you login dont have access...for host file enter qwe and ip of the Server.

Answer (score 0):

There might be something wrong with the config so i recommend not to do anything with config but you can follow below steps if there is no risk in it.

1. Delete the web app (and site collection), and all newly created App Pools
2. Re-Create the Web App using the SharePoint Central Administration with new App Pool
3. Re-Create site collection
4. Go into IIS settings and verify the new site is in there and active
5. Go into the Application pools and the app pool is started or NOT, If not than start app pool
6. Check that the Central Admin is started or not.